# htaccess rewriting outside the root

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite from this url :

```
my domain/myapp/index.php?lang=es
```

to:

```
my domain/myapp/es/
```

with the following commands on the .htaccess file on the root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^myapp/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?lang=$1
RewriteRule ^myapp/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?lang=$1
```

but i didn't succeed

Answer (score 0):

Your code has to work fine.
If you are using Apache server, make sure it is configured right:

Make sure this string is uncommented in httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Make sure that there is:

```
AllowOverride All
```

in the Directory section instead of:

```
AllowOverride None
```

Section should look like:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    llow from all
</Directory>
```

With correctly configured server your .htaccess file works fine on my machine.